# Same color on two different sites is not the same

Tags: colors, mismatch

I'm stumped. I simply am trying to match a color from one site to another site, and when I use the exact same HEX# as a TD bgcolor, and view the two sites next to each other in the same browser, the color is slightly different. Am I just overlooking something obvious?

site 1: http://web.vanderbilt.edu/resources/standards
taking the "Brighter Gold" #E7B850, which if you look at its source is just shown as a td bgcolor="#E7B850".

And doing the same thing in a table cell on another site, adding the bgcolor="#E7B850" to a td, to me, doesn't look the same.

site 2: http://vanderbilt-adec.org
You'll see a big table cell midway down the page with this color in it.

So, if you view these two sites side-by-side, do those two color blocks look the same to you?

Comment: I've reverted the "please disregard" message, as we encourage posters not to damage questions once they have found their answer. I'll cast a "cannot reproduce" close vote, and that might make it deletable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when I look at your page, it seems you took the "Dark Gold / D8AB4C" instead of the "Brighter Gold E7B850". Also when I look at the source of your site, I find the following:

```
<td width="350" valign="top" bgcolor="#d8ab4c">
    <div>
        <ol class="listschools">        
            <li>Al Ahad</li>
            <li>Al Dhaher</li>
            <li>Al Diwan</li>
            <li>Al Husoon</li>
            <li>Al Jahilli</li>
            <li>Al Khalif</li>
            <li>Al Khatem</li>
            <li>Al Shiyam</li>
            <li>Al Somou</li>
            <li>Mezyad</li>
            <li>Maryam Bint Sultan</li>
            <li>Mubarak Bin Mohammed</li>
            <li>Rawdat Al Atfal</li>
            <li>Rawdat Al Mushrif</li>
            <li>Rawdat Al Oula</li>
            <li>Um Ghafa</li>
            <li>Wagan</li>
            <li>Yas</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</td>
```

Wich clearly indicates that you've used the Dark Gold color.

Comment: DOH!!!!! i'm SO sorry to my fellow stackers. and to you, Rowin, for wasting your time! it was very late and i hadn't gotten much sleep in days. i simply didn't upload the latest version of my file and was comparing to a prior version with that darker color. geese, my apologies. please forgive me for wasting this space.

Comment: if there's a way (i haven't found one) to delete this whole post, i will.